# Help wiring 1-pole switch + USB in single outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have the two products below and I need them to go in a single gang box that used to be a simple 1-pole switch.

Product pages:

- http://www.legrand.ca/adorne/select/switches/aspd1531w8.aspx
- http://www.legrand.ca/adorne/select/outlets/arusbw4.aspx

PDF's:

- http://www.legrand.ca/~/media/adorne/Products/Documents/is/USBoutlet_ARUSB_INSTL_8-24.ashx
- http://www.legrand.ca/~/media/adorne/Products/Documents/is/PaddleSwitch1M_ASPD1531_6-18.ashx

Now I need the USB outlet (1 hot, 1 neutral) to always have power while the switch (1 hot, 1  3-way, 1 one-pole) will only pass power through when on. Wall plate has the ground.

There are three incoming wires (1 hot, 1 neutral, 1 ground).

---

Desired states:

1. switch is on: USB has power, light has power
2. switch is off: USB has power, light does not have power

How do I need to wire this up to achieve these states?

Comment: Maybe all neutrals connected but put the USB hot into the switched 3-way?

Comment: ^ The above is also a no-go.

Comment: Are you sure the ground wire is not another hot wire (the load)? If it is a ground wire, you need to have two hots, line and load. Load goes to the COM screw (should be black), line connects on the other side, and then neutral below the line. I have it wired this way and it works exactly as you would like it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switched circuit, and the USB outlet, hook up in parallel.

REVISED DIAGRAM, after figuring out that the mention of three-way switch was a red herring:

```
FROM POWER SOURCE:     SWITCH                           TO CONTROLLED LOAD

HOT  __________________./ .__________________________________ Switched Hot
          |             
          |
          |_____________.   
                          USB OUTLET   
           _____________.
          |   
NEUTRAL __|__________________________________________________ Neutral (if present) 

GROUND ______________________________________________________ Ground (if present)
          |
          |_____________. BOX GROUND
```

The USB is connected to hot and neutral.

The switch is connected between hot and the switched load.

Saftey ground for the box is connected to ground.

If the switched hot is bundled with a neutral, that is also connected to neutral.

If the switched hot is bundled with a ground, that is also connected to safety ground.

Note that **a three-way switch is not required in this case.** If that's what you bought  you can use it, but you'll do so by connecting only one of the switch's outputs and leaving the other unconnected.

Also note that a switch sharing a box with a house-current outlet on the same branch is exactly the same as I've shown here, with that outlet replacing the USB transformer and its outlet. This may not be obvious if the previous unit combined the outlet and switch into a single component, but that's what's happening internally.

Comment: Thanks for the info and I believe I already tried the configuration you mentioned the first time. What I saw however was that the light switch portion worked but the UBS charging only worked in the off position and exhibited the issues outlined here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/usb-wall-outlet-charger-not-working

Comment: If you did what I described, it would work. So you didn't.

Comment: I could use more explanation here: "Incoming neutral to neutral on USB and outgoing neutral. (Attach a pigtail from the USB, and connect this, the outgoing neutral, and the incoming neutral together with a wire nut.)" - What is the outgoing neutral you are referring to?

Comment: There are three incoming wires (1 hot, 1 neutral, 1 ground). That is all that is in the box I'm working in.

Comment: Is there a free circuit drawing tool I could use to map out what I have done?

Comment: Well they are all going out of the box and I am not sure where they are going to and coming from physically. All I know is the previous single light switch had 1 hot, 1 neutral, and 1 ground hooked up to it. Either the circuit was open or closed and either the light and outlet were on or the light and outlet were off. Now I am attempting to replace this single 2 state switch with the switch and USB outlet listed above. They both fit side-by-side in a single gang box. I think the main problem at this point is that the USB outlet is just not working properly as outlined in the link:

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/usb-wall-outlet-charger-not-working

Comment: Adding another sketch, since it sounds like part of the problem is that we started from a bad description.

Comment: So as discovered in the other question, I'm dealing with two hots, white neutral is false neutral. The diagram you made is exactly how I wired it the first time but given that the neutral isn't actually a neutral in my case, it's not going to work as intended for the USB which needs a proper neutral. Would it work if I wired the USB's neutral to ground perhaps?

Comment: Hot to neutral and hot to ground being 120VAC makes sense. "Two hots" *might* make sense if the outlet and light were wired to be on separate circuits. There is no such thing as "false neutral" unless the wiring is flat-out wrong. NOTHING but safety ground should ever connect to safety ground. Protect yourself and your house: Get someone who actually knows what they're doing to look at this. You've got a situation which can not be reliably diagnosed over the Internet.

Comment: Sorry I said that completely wrong: (since *hot* to ground is 120vac, and *neutral* to ground is also 120vac) I think this may be the only configuration without digging for more wires that will work. ie both *hot* and *neutral* are hot (white and black)

Comment: NO. Whether it works, and whether it's appropriate, are different things. There are good reasons for conforming to code, and I can't endorse departing from it. I stand by "NOTHING". On the other issue: I'm not suggesting you hire someone, I'm suggesting you find a more qualified local amateur to work through this with you. You aren't incompetent, but the questions you're asking are basic enough to suggest that you will learn much more working directly with someone than trying to do it with nothing but the Internet as assistance, and your odds of a working and safe outcome will be much higher.

Comment: If "neutral to ground is 120V" it isn't neutral, or the wiring is damaged. You need to establish which and address it properly.

Comment: Ok let me provide some updated info: I turned off the circuit, unplugged all the leads, and tested black to ground and white to ground. I got 120vac from white to ground and 0vac from black to ground so for whatever reason the colors were wired backwards. I should be able to get it wired correctly now.