# USB wall outlet charger not working

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

By not working I mean even when installed in the simplest configuration, it does some sort of low power pulsating. It will cycle between charging and not charging a USB device every half second or so.

By simplest configuration I mean hot to hot, neutral to neutral, ground to ground.

I am using this USB wall outlet: http://www.legrand.ca/adorne/select/outlets/arusbw4.aspx#res [[PDF](http://www.legrand.ca/~/media/adorne/Products/Documents/is/USBoutlet_ARUSB_INSTL_8-24.ashx)]

I also have a night light in a wall outlet connected to the same circuit and while the phone charging connects and disconnects, the nightlight fluctuates a low illumination automatically becoming brighter, dimming, and becoming brighter again, etc.

What is wrong with this configuration or is it the USB unit causing problems?

Comment: Sounds like bad connections and/or and overloaded circuit and/or a malfunctioning USB power supply. Can't answer which without putting a meter on it.

Comment: What devices are being plugged into it?  Do they exceed 2.1 amps?

Comment: I've tried an HTC One so far. Certainly shouldn't be exceeding 2.1 amps. I'll work on testing the USB port with a multimeter.

Comment: Is this the same question you asked an hour previous? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55569/help-wiring-1-pole-switch-usb-in-single-outlet

Comment: @user20127: no that is a wiring question, this is about whether or not a component is working and what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that the hot is actually hot? Not to insult, but verify that the hot and neutral are identified and connected correctly. Use meter to go from hot to ground and verify voltage and neutral to ground to verify no voltage.

Comment: I tested both white and black to ground and both read 120V AC. So according to what your saying, both are hot in this case?

Comment: If that's really true, something was definitely wired incorrectly. You need to find that and fix it, or get someone to find it and fix it. On the other hand, given your other question, I recommend that you get someone to check your work.

Comment: It works with a standard 3 prong outlet also on the same circuit so maybe there are more wires hidden just outside this box I can't see that are the travelling/neutral wires.